# Extract set of repeated pattern from String literal in Java

Tags: java, regex

What would be a convenient and reliable way to extract all the "{...}" tags from a given string? (Using Java).

So, to give an example:
Say I have: `http://www.something.com/{tag1}/path/{tag2}/else/{tag3}.html`

I want to get all the "{}” tags; I was thinking about using the Java .split() functions, but not sure what the correct regex would be for this.

Note also: tags can be called anything, not just tagX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use regular expressions to match this. Something like this could work for your expression:

```
String regex = "\\{.*?\\}";
```

As this will "reluctantly" match any sub string that has { and } surrounding it.  The `.*?` makes it find any character between the { and }, but reluctantly, so it doesn't match the bigger String:

```
{tag1}/path/{tag2}/else/{tag3}
```

which would be a "greedy" match. Note that the curly braces in the regex need to be escaped with double backslashes since curly braces have a separate meaning inside a regular expression, and if you want to indicate the curly brace String, you need to escape it.

e.g.,

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String test = "http://www.something.com/{tag1}/path/{tag2}/else/{tag3}.html";
      String regex = "\\{.*?\\}";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

      while (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group());
      }
   }
```

With an output of:

```
{tag1}
{tag2}
{tag3}
```

You can read more about regular expressions here:
[Oracle Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)

and for greater detail, here:
[www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: `"{[^{}]*}"` might be better? (escapes were ignored)

Comment: @Kent: `"{[^{}]*}"` looks illegal to me. Why not test it out?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I just omitted the escapes. well, if fit it in grep, it should be: `grep -oE "\{[^{}]*\}"`  java needs more "\"s.

Comment: @Kent: that should work well too. I can't say though which one is "better" though.

Comment: Btw: what would be the regex to return just the insides of the {tags}, i.e. “tag1”, “tag2”, “tag3”, etc.?

Comment: @Larry: to find content in the curly braces but not including the braces, you would need to use look aheads and look behinds. I think something like this could work: `String regex = "(?<=\\{).*?(?=\\})";`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually, when I try this: String txt="http://www.something.com/{tag1}/path/{{tag2}}/else/{{tag3}}”; it returns: “tag1”, “{tag2”, “{tag”. Could we ensure a way to avoid this?

Comment: If you're going to nest braces, then things get messy. You may not be able to use regular expressions for this, especially if you don't know how many levels of nesting is possible. Instead you may need to look into parsing the String with some sort of parser.

Comment: Ok, actually I was only testing it out with some extreme errors, this is unlikely to happen.